# Extracting numbers surrounded by parenthesis with grep

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sed, grep

What should I write to find sublines like this `(3894569)` ?

I have tried `\\([0-9]*\\)`

but it ,for example in line

```
wiluefh/u3:2(920)
```

finds `3` and `2` and `920`

I want only `920` so what I must improve?

My task was to print PID of process and subprocess using `awk` and `pstree`.

I have tried this

```
ps -aux | grep $1 | awk '( system("pstree -p " $2) )' | grep -oh "\ ([0-9]*\\)" > $2
```

`$1` is PID of process

`$2` is file name

Comment: Please show the commands you tried and some more useful sample input and output data.

Comment: In pstree row i want to print all subrows : (some nambers)

Comment: they contain PID of process or subprocess

Comment: Please [format your code properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777) and try to provide an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: just use `grep -o '([0-9]*)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use character escaping twice. Delete / or ".

For example:

```
grep -oh "([0-9]*)" 

grep -oh \([0-9]*\)
```

Comment: `grep` uses [BREs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) by default, where, perhaps against expectations, `(` must be escaped as `\(` in order to be recognized as a regex metacharacter.

Comment: avoid double quotes unless needed for substitution